# Remove double quotes from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working with a dictionary which seems to behave like a string for the most part because it has double quotes across the dictionary encompassing the keys and values. I want to be able to index the dictionary, however the speech marks prevent me from doing so.

I have searched and found similar articles but the speech marks were on the keys as opposed to a size encompassing a dictionary.

Here's what I have:

```
{'0': {0: "{'address_components': [{'long_name': '238', 'short_name': '238', "
      "'types': ['street_number']}, {'long_name': 'Lincoln Street', "
      "'short_name': 'Lincoln St', 'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': "
      "'Hahnville', 'short_name': 'Hahnville', 'types': ['locality', "
      "'political']}, {'long_name': 'St. Charles Parish', 'short_name': "
      "'St Charles Parish', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', "
      "'political']}, {'long_name': 'Louisiana', 'short_name': 'LA', "
      "'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, "
      "{'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US', 'types': "
      "['country', 'political']}, {'long_name': '70057', 'short_name': "
      "'70057', 'types': ['postal_code']}], 'formatted_address': '238 "
      "Lincoln St, Hahnville, LA 70057, USA', 'geometry': {'bounds': "
      "{'northeast': {'lat': 29.9765067, 'lng': -90.4105124}, 'southwest': "
      "{'lat': 29.9763491, 'lng': -90.4107531}}, 'location': {'lat': "
      "29.97642, 'lng': -90.4106589}, 'location_type': 'ROOFTOP', "
      "'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 29.9777768802915, 'lng': "
      "-90.4092837697085}, 'southwest': {'lat': 29.9750789197085, 'lng': "
      "-90.4119817302915}}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJu32jB3_PIIYRMF2Utx14Ouc', "
      "'types': ['premise']}"}}
```

And what I have tried:

```
import ast
final_s = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in p]
```

Which returns the wrong expected results.

The expected result should remove the double speech marks:

```
{'0': {0: {'address_components': [{'long_name': '238', 'short_name': '238', 'types':
   ['street_number']}, {'long_name': 'Lincoln Street', 'short_name': 'Lincoln St',
   'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': 'Hahnville', 'short_name': 'Hahnville', 'types':
   ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'St. Charles Parish', 'short_name': 'St.
  Charles Parish', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
 {'long_name':   'Louisiana', 'short_name': 'LA', 'types':
 ['administrative_area_level_1',   'political']}, {'long_name': 'United States',
 'short_name': 'US', 'types': ['country',   'political']}, {'long_name': '70057',
 'short_name': '70057', 'types':   ['postal_code']}], 'formatted_address': '238 Lincoln
 St, Hahnville, LA 70057, USA',   'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat':
 29.9765067, 'lng': -90.4105124},   'southwest': {'lat': 29.9763491, 'lng':
 -90.4107531}}, 'location': {'lat': 29.97642,   'lng': -90.4106589}, 'location_type':
 'ROOFTOP', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat':   29.9777768802915, 'lng':
 -90.4092837697085}, 'southwest': {'lat': 29.9750789197085,   'lng':
 -90.4119817302915}}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJu32jB3_PIIYRMF2Utx14Ouc', 'types':
   ['premise']}}}
```

And allow for me to index within the list:

```
p[0]
```

Comment: if you want to use the key '0' which is first element try `p['0']` if you want to use 0 which is an element of key '0' try `p['0'][0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 levels (`'0'` and `0`) in the nested dictionary:

```
p = {
    '0':
        {
            0:
                "{'address_components': [{'long_name': '238', 'short_name': '238', 'types': ['street_number']}, {'long_name': 'Lincoln Street', 'short_name': 'Lincoln St', 'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': 'Hahnville', 'short_name': 'Hahnville', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'St. Charles Parish', 'short_name': 'St Charles Parish', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Louisiana', 'short_name': 'LA', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US', 'types': ['country', 'political']}, {'long_name': '70057', 'short_name': '70057', 'types': ['postal_code']}], 'formatted_address': '238 Lincoln St, Hahnville, LA 70057, USA', 'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 29.9765067, 'lng': -90.4105124}, 'southwest': {'lat': 29.9763491, 'lng': -90.4107531}}, 'location': {'lat': 29.97642, 'lng': -90.4106589}, 'location_type': 'ROOFTOP', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 29.9777768802915, 'lng': -90.4092837697085}, 'southwest': {'lat': 29.9750789197085, 'lng': -90.4119817302915}}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJu32jB3_PIIYRMF2Utx14Ouc', 'types': ['premise']}"
        }
}

import ast, pprint

for k, value in p.items():
    for sk, subValue in value.items():
        p[k][sk] = ast.literal_eval(subValue)

pprint.pprint(p)
```

Out:

```
{'0': {0: {'address_components': [{'long_name': '238',
                                   'short_name': '238',
                                   'types': ['street_number']},
                                  {'long_name': 'Lincoln Street',
                                   'short_name': 'Lincoln St',
                                   'types': ['route']},
                                  {'long_name': 'Hahnville',
                                   'short_name': 'Hahnville',
                                   'types': ['locality', 'political']},
                                  {'long_name': 'St. Charles Parish',
                                   'short_name': 'St Charles Parish',
                                   'types': ['administrative_area_level_2',
                                             'political']},
                                  {'long_name': 'Louisiana',
                                   'short_name': 'LA',
                                   'types': ['administrative_area_level_1',
                                             'political']},
                                  {'long_name': 'United States',
                                   'short_name': 'US',
                                   'types': ['country', 'political']},
                                  {'long_name': '70057',
                                   'short_name': '70057',
                                   'types': ['postal_code']}],
           'formatted_address': '238 Lincoln St, Hahnville, LA 70057, USA',
           'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 29.9765067,
                                                 'lng': -90.4105124},
                                   'southwest': {'lat': 29.9763491,
                                                 'lng': -90.4107531}},
                        'location': {'lat': 29.97642, 'lng': -90.4106589},
                        'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
                        'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 29.9777768802915,
                                                   'lng': -90.4092837697085},
                                     'southwest': {'lat': 29.9750789197085,
                                                   'lng': -90.4119817302915}}},
           'place_id': 'ChIJu32jB3_PIIYRMF2Utx14Ouc',
           'types': ['premise']}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't concerned about security (depends how you acquire those strings). You can use the `exec()` command on the string

For example if you want to get info from your example (dubbed as `input` you can do the following)

```py
exec("real_dict="+input['0'][0])
```

and now you can do anything you want on the `real_dict` like it was a normal dictionary.

Printing out real_dict would result you in:

```
{'address_components': [{'long_name': '238',
   'short_name': '238',
   'types': ['street_number']},
  {'long_name': 'Lincoln Street',
   'short_name': 'Lincoln St',
   'types': ['route']},
  {'long_name': 'Hahnville',
   'short_name': 'Hahnville',
   'types': ['locality', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'St. Charles Parish',
   'short_name': 'St Charles Parish',
   'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'Louisiana',
   'short_name': 'LA',
   'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'United States',
   'short_name': 'US',
   'types': ['country', 'political']},
  {'long_name': '70057', 'short_name': '70057', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
 'formatted_address': '238 Lincoln St, Hahnville, LA 70057, USA',
 'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 29.9765067, 'lng': -90.4105124},
   'southwest': {'lat': 29.9763491, 'lng': -90.4107531}},
  'location': {'lat': 29.97642, 'lng': -90.4106589},
  'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
  'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 29.9777768802915,
    'lng': -90.4092837697085},
   'southwest': {'lat': 29.9750789197085, 'lng': -90.4119817302915}}},
 'place_id': 'ChIJu32jB3_PIIYRMF2Utx14Ouc',
 'types': ['premise']}
```

Now you can do this to the whole input dictionary with dictionary comprehension.